# OpenLayers WFS-T tinyows insert transaction: error GID value

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, wfs-t

I try to implement insertion of new point using Openlayers v2.13 saveStrategy calling tinyows which implements the WFS-T transaction; I use the example from http://mapserver.org/tinyows/openlayershowto.html  - the code is exactly the same except for the layer.

I have two questions:

1) adding a new point implements a transaction which uses "MULTIPOINT" but my postgis layer is of type POINT - is there a way to force "POINT" ? My solution up to now is to use a TRIGGER in postgresql to do an INSTEAD OF to change MULTIPOINT TO POINT.

2) I get an error because the insertion creates a "gid" value which should not be included, as it is added by default by the counter. The TINYOWS log give me the following transaction and error:

SQL

> INSERT INTO "arch_geo_dbt"."p030104_v" ("gid","the_geom") VALUES ('042159162153000033','010400002031BF0D00010000000101000000B69CF08B3069314130B8664669AD5541')

ERROR:

> ERROR: value "042159162153000033" is out of range for type integer

Below my XML from the REQUEST POST

```
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><wfs:Insert><feature:dbtcivici xmlns:feature="http://www.tinyows.org/"><feature:the_geom><gml:MultiPoint xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:900913"><gml:pointMember><gml:Point><gml:pos>1141040.5466402 5682597.1000195</gml:pos></gml:Point></gml:pointMember></gml:MultiPoint></feature:the_geom></feature:dbtcivici></wfs:Insert></wfs:Transaction>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The point was that tinyows (version 1.0.0) when adding a new feature when getting a "insert" transaction request, adds a random string as GID. Now GID is either an integer or a biginteger, and defaults to  NEXTVAL(sequence)  in the Postgres/Postgis table. The GID that tinyows created was too big (out of range).

Tinyows works fine with a table, but the table I was trying to update was a **VIEW** (of course I was using triggers to update the tables behind the views, as views are not updateble). Tinyows allows to set pkey="gid" in the layer object in its config.xml file, nevertheless if it is a view it probably does not understand the type (i.e. integer).

MY SOLUTION:  in the view, **CAST the GID column to text type**, so the insert does not throw an error, and then in the triggers forget the GID value created by tinyows, and use the correct **NEXTVAL()**.

If anyone is interested I can post my trigger routine.